# Unable to see data from <html> form submit in PHP

Tags: php, html, database, forms, authentication

I am a newbie in web developing and I am having a hard time fixing a little bug in my code.

**Expected outcome:**

1. Retrieve $_POST data in PHP and login user

**What's happening:**

1. Page refreshes but query doesn't return anything.

**php:**

```
if( isset($POST["login"])){
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["name"]);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["pw"]);
    $select = "SELECT * 
               FROM tbl_accounts 
               WHERE uname = '".$username."' 
               AND pass = '".$password."' ";

    $check = mysqli_query($conn, $select);
    if( mysqli_num_rows($check)){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('yahoo!')</script>";
    } else {
        $message = "Invalid Email-Password Combination";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
    }
}
```

**html form:**

```
<div class="signin">
    <span class="signinfont">Sign In</span>
    <form 
        method="POST" 
        class="testform"
        action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>">
        <input class="cred" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Username">
        <input class="cred" type="password" name="pw" placeholder="Password">
        <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Why did you remove your code and replace it with an image? please post your actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO & the wonderful world of web dev.

**Change:**

```
$POST
```

**To:**

```
$_POST // <-- note the _
```

on line 1 of your PHP file.

As noted in other answers, you can always make use of [$_REQUEST](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) as well.

> **$_Request**: 
>   
> *An associative array that by default contains the contents of $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE_.*

Your form could be written as follows:

---

**HTML Form:**

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>">
  <input class="cred" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Username">
  <input class="cred" type="password" name="pw" placeholder="Password">
  <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
</form>
```

---

**PHP:**

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST["name"]);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST["pw"]);
    $select = "SELECT * 
               FROM tbl_accounts 
               WHERE uname = '".$username."' 
               AND pass = '".$password."' ";

    $check = mysqli_query($conn, $select);
    if( mysqli_num_rows($check)){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('yahoo!')</script>";
    } else {
        $message = "Invalid Email-Password Combination";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
    }
}
```

You can make use of [var_dump](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) to debug this moving forward as well.

FWIW, if I could go back in time to when I first started learning PHP I would have just started with a framework. A lot of good scaffolding is already in place *( I see your passwords are stored in plain-text in your example code )*. [Laravel](https://laravel.com) is a good choice. I've heard good things about [CakePHP](https://cakephp.org/) as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing:

```
$POST
```

*to*

```
$_POST
```

in the if statement

Answer (score 0):

yes, please **$POST** replace through **$_POST**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $_REQUEST also instead of $_POST. If you change it to REQUEST,
 your code looks like below

```
if( isset($_RESUEST["login"]))
{

  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_RESUEST["name"]);
  $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_RESUEST["pw"]);
  $select = "SELECT * 
           FROM tbl_accounts 
           WHERE uname = '".$username."' 
           AND pass = '".$password."' ";

  $check = mysqli_query($conn, $select);
  if( mysqli_num_rows($check))
 {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('yahoo!')</script>";
 } 
 else 
 {
    $message = "Invalid Email-Password Combination";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
 }
}
```

Comment: You say to use `$_REQUEST` but you copy-pasted `$_RESUEST`